# How come the Earth is not crumbling into the core due to fact that the core is in the middle of it?

Tags: thermodynamics, newtonian-gravity, geophysics

I always wondered why isn't the Earth shrinking or melting because of the core.

Comment: Why do you think it should collapse?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15169/24774

Comment: *Core* means the central or middle part of something. Most things have a core, but it doesn't necessarily make them collapse.

Comment: @sammy: methinks OP is intending to ask about the (extreme) *temperature* of the core and not its *existence*, as you are implying there.

Comment: The earth is mostly a big drop of melted rock, with a crust of lighter rock floating on the surface, and us walking around on top of that. If we sunk in, some of that melted rock would have to come up, because it's pretty incompressible. In fact it happens all the time, at subduction zones, volcanoes, and mid-ocean ridges.

Comment: @KyleKanos : It is not clear what effect the OP is asking about - the crust melting because of the heat of the core, or sinking because the core is liquid, or shrinking because of the heat (why not expanding?), or being pulled inwards by gravity. The title suggests that anything with a core should implode - no reason given.

Comment: I am talking about the gravity and heat of the core

Comment: Its pretty obvious that the Earth is not shrinking or melting into the core, because we can observe that it isn't.  Questions like this are really centered around the fact that you have a mental model of how the world should work that is not correct.  Good news: you've noticed this oddity and you decided to ask for help.  Bad news: we really need you to explain why you think the earth should shrink/melt because we need to understand what your mental model actually is before we can really help you improve it.  We need more than a few words to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Gravity pulls material towards the centre, whereas heat (the kinetic energy of the particles) causes pressure which enables matter to resist being compressed. The two forces are balanced. If one were greater than the other, the Earth would contract or expand until balance is reached.

The same balance between pressure and gravity keeps stars (which are a million times more massive than the Earth) from collapsing.